# Using ROW_NUMBER instead of MAX()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060035/get-the-mothertongue-and-the-fluent-language-of-an-employee). I have the following query to get the mother tongue and the fluent languages for an employee :

```
SELECT
        lan.AdminFileId
       ,MAX(lan.MotherTongue) AS MotherTongue
       ,MAX(lan.Fluent) AS Fluent
    FROM (SELECT
            al.AdminFileId
           ,MAX(CASE
                WHEN al.LanguageLevelId = 4 THEN l.Label
            END) AS MotherTongue
           ,MAX(CASE
                WHEN al.LanguageLevelId = 2 THEN l.Label
            END) AS Fluent
        FROM AF_Language al
        LEFT JOIN AF_AdminFile aaf ON aaf.AdminFileId=al.AdminFileId
        INNER JOIN Employee e ON e.AdminFileId=aaf.AdminFileId

        LEFT JOIN Language l ON al.LanguageId = l.ID
        GROUP BY al.AdminFileId
                ,l.Label
                ,al.LanguageLevelId) AS lan
    GROUP BY lan.AdminFileId
```

The output is like below :

```
AdminFileId MotherTongue Fluent
45          English      French
67          Spanish      English
88          Arabic       English
```

How can I use ROW_NUMBER to get the same result?
Essentially

Comment: What is it exactly that you don't understand? There are many examples online, weren't they clear? And have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't understand why you have a subquery here... I don't understand how your query is returning accurate results to begin with. Finding the `max()` of your language text field seems like a very strange way to go about things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to use `ROW_NUMBER()`, use `AdminFileId` only in `GROUP BY` clause will have only single entry :

```
SELECT al.AdminFileId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN al.LanguageLevelId = 4 THEN l.Label END) AS MotherTongue,
       MAX(CASE WHEN al.LanguageLevelId = 2 THEN l.Label END) AS Fluent
FROM AF_Language al LEFT JOIN 
     AF_AdminFile aaf 
     ON aaf.AdminFileId = al.AdminFileId LEFT JOIN -- Used LEFT JOIN INSTEAD OF INNER
     Employee e 
     ON e.AdminFileId = aaf.AdminFileId LEFT JOIN 
     Language l 
     ON al.LanguageId = l.ID
GROUP BY al.AdminFileId;
```

EDIT : Using `row_number` :

```
SELECT al.AdminFileId, l.Label,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY al.AdminFileId 
                          ORDER BY (CASE WHEN al.LanguageLevelId = 4 
                                         THEN 1 ELSE 2
                                    END)
                         ) AS Seq
FROM AF_Language al LEFT JOIN 
     AF_AdminFile aaf 
     ON aaf.AdminFileId = al.AdminFileId LEFT JOIN -- Used LEFT JOIN INSTEAD OF INNER
     Employee e 
     ON e.AdminFileId = aaf.AdminFileId LEFT JOIN 
     Language l 
     ON al.LanguageId = l.ID
WHERE al.LanguageLevelId IN (4, 2);
```

Then you can use sub-query :

```
SELECT AdminFileId,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Seq = 1 THEN Label END) AS MotherTongue,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Seq = 2 THEN Label END) AS Fluent
FROM ( <Query> 
     ) t
GROUP BY AdminFileId;
```

Comment: It's still weird and nonsensical, but at least it doesn't have the superfluous subquery anymore.